# DashDB Entry Plan sunset and databases lost

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I recently noticed that mi dashDB entry plan under a dedicated ibm cloud environment has been sunset. I read an article that said that, but i had not been informed previously, so i lost my two databases (production, and testing).

Does anyone know what i should do in this case? I have a lot of sensible data inside them, and i didn´t have any problem about changing the plan, but i don´t know how to do it because i cannot get inside the console (it doesn´t work anymore). Is there any way to recover my databases? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming and should be addressed to the vendor support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a support ticket here: https://watson.service-now.com/wcp

The support team can temporarily re-enable your access so that you can download a copy of your data.

Comment: Ok, i appreciate the answer. So i will do that. Then, what alternative plan do i have to re-create my bases? Because i can´t see any plan of db2 from my cloud console. Thanks!

Comment: Forget it, they told me about the alternative plans, thanks!!!